# how to access dictionary inside list javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

I want to extract the longitude and latitude coordinates of each restaurant:

```html
<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.7749, -122.4194], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);

    let temp = '{{ output_info }}'; 
    console.log(temp);

    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        var restaurant = temp[i];
        console.log(restaurant);
        var marker = L.marker([restaurant['latitude'], restaurant['longitude']]).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup("<b>" + restaurant['name'] + "</b><br>" + restaurant['address'] + "<br>" + restaurant['city'] + ", " + restaurant['state'] + " " + restaurant['postal_code']).openPopup();

        if (i === 0) {
            map.flyTo([restaurant['latitude'], restaurant['longitude']], 16);
        }
    }
</script>
```

in my results.html console:

[{'name': "McDonald's", 'latitude': '27.8931987958', 'longitude': '-82.3198442906'}, {'name': 'Cafe Baladi', 'latitude': '40.041639063', 'longitude': '-75.5428394303'}, {'name': 'Chick-fil-A', 'latitude': '38.599651', 'longitude': '-90.446909'}]

main:25 [

Why is console.log(restaurant) giving me [ and not the first dictionary?

i looked at my app.py and util.py files to see if im passing anything in wrong and it seems alright (based on what im seeing in the console). so honestly not sure what's really happening? i just want to get the coordinates for every restaurant so i can plop them on a map

Comment: try this and show me the result `console.log(typeof temp)`

Comment: Isn't the first console log that's outputting this?

Comment: @AousMohammad it prints string

Comment: try to put after this:
`let oldData = '{{ output_info }}';`
`let temp = eval(oldData)`; , and tell me what will happen ***don't use eval as a final solution it's dangerous***

Answer (score 0):

Use the jinja filter [`tojson`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.tojson) to make the list javascript compatible.

```js
let temp = {{ output_info | tojson }}; 
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: this is my first time I hear about jinja :D with what you use it ?

Comment: @AousMohammad Jinja is Flask's built-in template engine. You use this to render your HTML template via `render_template`.